# can i use opencv using haar detect children faces by using adult faces as positive samples?

Tags: opencv

I'm new in haar cascade and i would like to know if it is possible to detect children faces by using adult faces as positive samples, or it will need children faces for the positive samples?

Comment: Yes, you should get quite good results. You should try it rather than asking here, it is very small code. :)
Happy Coding.

Comment: the code is simple yes, but i need a clarification because i need alot of samples to get the best result and the training time quite long..so it is possible using the adults faces as positive samples to detect children faces right? thanks mate

Comment: You don't need train or make `haar` for yourself. You can use some-one else' `haar` and use them directly. OpenCV has one as an example at **/path/to/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml**
You can download more sophisticated haar online. Here is a link: http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34/
I assume you have code to execute over this or you can get easily online.

Comment: yeah, i know and used that xml, but they didnt state whether it use adult faces only or both adult and children faces as their samples, and i want to make my own xml file, thats why i ask as post above.

Comment: In that case, I suggest, you can use adult's face without problem unless target contains some very little kids(only few days old :P ).
And if you are going to make your own `haar`, why don't you yourself add kids faces also. I don't see any additional effort.
PS: Please add full detail of problem and the extent of try/experiment and results to better judge and solve the problem. :)

Comment: yeah, will work on that tomorrow, and will post any the results here soon :D, thanks Pervez

Comment: hi again,sorry for the late update, im done with the haar training and get a good detection, however when i run performance.exe to check the hitrate, it run and after done it autoclose..how to make it not autoclose? or i did something wrong?

Comment: Hi there, I am posting this suggestion as answer as it seem to be working. You can vote-up/accept as answer if it helped. This will help other answer seekers. I see you have posted another question on SO regarding this new problem, I will get back to you on that question (here it will be off topic) to discuss appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adult's face `HAAR` without problem unless target contains some very little kids(only few days old :P ). All the basic features for kids and adults are same.

And if you are going to make your own `HAAR`, you can yourself add kids faces also. There shall not be any additional effort. Be sure to cover wide varieties.

PS: Also, You don't need train or make `haar` for yourself. You can use some-one else' `haar` and use them directly. OpenCV has one as an example at

> /path/to/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

You can download more sophisticated haar online. Here is a link:

> alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34

I assume you have code to execute over this or you can get easily online.

Happy Coding :)